# Синие полосы при выделении

Tags: html, css

Доброго утречка!

Откуда взялись синие полосы при выделении (скриншот) и как их убрать? Прикладываю
CSS и HTML

CSS:

```
#middle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 260px;
    background: url('img/middlebg.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

    p.middle {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 1.125em;
        color: #ffffff;
        left: 25%;
        top: 45%;
        padding-left: 1%;
    }

    p.middledown {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 0.875em;
        color: #ffffff;
        left: 22.6%;
        top: 55%;
        padding-left: 1%;
    }

    .fa-briefcase {
        position: relative;
        color: #fff;
        display: inline-block;
        left: 25%;
        top: 55%;
    }

    .fa-clock-o {
        position: relative;
        color: #fff;
        display: inline-block;
        left: 25.2%;
        top: 54%;
    }

    .fa-heart-o {
        position: relative;
        color: #fff;
        display: inline-block;
        left: 25.2%;
        top: 54%;
    }

    .fa-rss {
        position: relative;
        color: #fff;
        display: inline-block;
        left: 25.2%;
        top: 54%;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="middle">

    <i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <p class="middle">548</p><p class="middledown">PROJECTS COMPLETE</p>

    <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <p class="middle">812</p><p class="middledown">WORKING HOURS</p>

    <i class="fa fa-rss fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <p class="middle">610</p><p class="middledown">POSITIVE FEEDBACKS</p>

    <i class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <p class="middle">735</p><p class="middledown">HAPPY CLIENTS</p>

</div>
```

[image: Синие полосы]

Comment: После обновления стр. проблема остается?

Comment: @Elena Остается.

Comment: @Elena - Нет, текст я выделил специально, я отметил то, что выше - над текстом вот эти вертикальные полосы... Они должны быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эти отступы появляются из-за `inline-block;`. О том как от них избавиться есть уже достаточно много статей, вариантов. [Одна из них.](http://css-live.ru/articles/zagadochnye-otstupy-mezhdu-inlajn-blokami.html)

Например занулить `font-size` у родителя, а у потомков соответственно задать:

```css
#middle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 260px;
    background: url(https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/000);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  font-size: 0px;
}

p.middle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  color: #ffffff;
  left: 25%;
  top: 45%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

p.middledown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  color: #ffffff;
  left: 22.6%;
  top: 55%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

#middle .fa {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.fa-briefcase {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 25%;
  top: 55%;
}

.fa-clock-o {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 25.2%;
  top: 54%;
}

.fa-heart-o {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 25.2%;
  top: 54%;
}

.fa-rss {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 25.2%;
  top: 54%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<div id="middle">

    <i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <p class="middle">548</p><p class="middledown">PROJECTS COMPLETE</p>

    <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <p class="middle">812</p><p class="middledown">WORKING HOURS</p>

    <i class="fa fa-rss fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <p class="middle">610</p><p class="middledown">POSITIVE FEEDBACKS</p>

    <i class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <p class="middle">735</p><p class="middledown">HAPPY CLIENTS</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Elena, Примите поздравления с десятитысячной репутацией!

Answer (score 0):

Между `inline-block`ами есть пробелы, которые [следует убрать](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468550/178988).